# Proof of Tensor Products from Atiyah and Macdonald's Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I apologize in advance if this question is stupid, but I am self studying and I am having trouble deciphering the following notation in Atiyah and Macdonald's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra." Let $M,N$ be $A$-modules.

They give the definition of $M$ being a free module as $M$ being isomorphic to the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i$ where each $M_i$ is isomorphic to $A$ considered as itself an $A$-module.

In the proof of the existence of the tensor product, they mention the free module $A^{M\times N}$.

My question is, what exactly do elements of this free module look like?

Comment: I've updated your question to include the co-author of the book who you forgot to mention (and who taught me this material a very long time ago $\ddot{\smile}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^{M\times N}$ comprises functions from $M\times N$ to $A$ that are *finitely supported*, i.e., functions $f$ such that $f(x, y) = 0$ for all but finitely many pairs $(x,y)$. You can write elements of $A^{M\times N}$ as finite sums $a_{m_1n_1} + a_{m_2n_2} + \ldots + a_{m_kn_k}$, where $m_i \in M$, $n_i \in N$, $a_{m_in_i} \in A$, and $i = 1 \ldots k$ for some $k$.

Comment: In general what determines the support for these functions? For instance, if these modules are vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The support of $f : Z \to A$ is the set of all $z \in Z$ such that $f(z) = 0$ for all but finitely many $z$ (where in this case $Z = M \times N$ is a product set).

Comment: @RobArthan Right. Sorry, brainfart...